# relationship between E[log(X)] and E[X]

Tags: probability

$X_1 X_2$ are two random variables with their expectations $E[X_1]$ $E[X_2]$ and variances $Var[X_1]$ $Var[X_2]$ respectively.
$$X_1=\sum_{i}\lambda_i(v_i+m_i)^{2}$$
$$X_2=\sum_{i}\lambda_i(v_i+n_i)^{2}$$
$v_i$ are i.i.d standard Gaussian distributions with 0 mean and variance 1.

If we have  $E[X_1]\lt E[X_2]$ and $Var[X_1]=Var[X_2]$ by applying particular $m_i$ and $n_i$. My question is:

Can we conclude that
$$E[\log X_1]\lt E[\log X_2]?????$$

Thank you:)

Comment: Which examples did you check?

Comment: @Did I have made some refinement to my problem according to your comment.

Comment: If $Y_i \sim N(m_i,1)$ then the CF of $Y_i$ is $f_i(t)=e^{-m_i i t}e^{-t^2/2}$, hence:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]=-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left.f_i(t)\right|_{t=0}=m_i^2+1, $$
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_i^4]=\frac{d^4}{dt^4}\left.f_i(t)\right|_{t=0}=m_i^4+6m_i^2+3, $$
$$\operatorname{Var}[Y_i^2]=4m_i^2+2.$$
This gives that the condition $\mathbb{E}[X_1]<\mathbb{E}[X_2]$ translates into:
$$ \sum \lambda_i m_i^2 < \sum \lambda_i n_i^2 $$
and the condition $\operatorname{Var}[X_1]=\operatorname{Var}[X_2]$ translates into:
$$ \sum \lambda_i^2 m_i^2 = \sum \lambda_i^2 n_i^2. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y_i \sim N(m_i,1)$ then the CF of $Y_i$ is $f_i(t)=e^{-m_i i t}e^{-t^2/2}$, hence:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]=-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left.f_i(t)\right|_{t=0}=m_i^2+1, $$
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_i^4]=\frac{d^4}{dt^4}\left.f_i(t)\right|_{t=0}=m_i^4+6m_i^2+3, $$
$$\operatorname{Var}[Y_i^2]=4m_i^2+2.$$
This gives that the condition $\mathbb{E}[X_1]<\mathbb{E}[X_2]$ translates into:
$$ \sum \lambda_i m_i^2 < \sum \lambda_i n_i^2 $$
and the condition $\operatorname{Var}[X_1]=\operatorname{Var}[X_2]$ translates into:
$$ \sum \lambda_i^2 m_i^2 = \sum \lambda_i^2 n_i^2. $$

Assuming that $X$ is a positive random variable with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, a well-behaved CF and small skewness we have:
$$\log X = \log\mu + \log\frac{X}{\mu} = \log\mu + \log\left(1+\frac{X-\mu}{\mu}\right)=\log\mu+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{(X-\mu)^k}{k\,\mu^k}$$
and by taking expected values we get:
$$ \mathbb{E}[\log X] \approx \log\mu -\frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu^2}.$$
In this context, from $\mu_1<\mu_2$ and $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$ the inequality $\mathbb{E}[\log X_1]<\mathbb{E}[\log X_2]$ should follow.
However, to prove it for real we need good bounds for the higher central moments of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: Thank you :) Taylor expansion is a good approximation if the random variable is concentrated  around the mean at the most time. But we also need to consider the situation when the variance is large enough that the higher order elements of Taylor expansion cannot be omitted.

Comment: I still accept your answer because it does bring great help to my topic on hand. Thank you again!